# Export swf only playing 1 frame when timer goes for 20 seconds

Tags: loops, actionscript-3, flash, animation, frames

My animation is basically. 1 frame, with multiple instances of a movieclip of a blinking eye that plays randomly, for 20 seconds until the timer makes it stop. but since everything is just on one frame, whenever whenever I try to export a swf or anything, all I have is a one-frame animation. WHen I extend the frames, the blinking animation won't play. :C Any ideas?

Here's the code for the timer, on the first frame of the scene:

```
stop();
var nCount:Number = 10;
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, nCount);
var scene = this;

timer_txt.text = nCount.toString();
myTimer.start();

myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);

function countdown(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    nCount--;
    timer_txt.text = nCount.toString();
    if(nCount == 0)
    {
        trace("start");
        scene.gotoAndStop(2);

    }
}
```

and here is the code for the blinking animation, on the first frame of the eye movieclip.

```
gotoAndPlay(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 150));
```

Comment: Let me guess. You export some kind of video or PNG sequence.

Comment: I ultimately need to end up with a frame animation I can import into Photoshop. PNG sequences were all the same frame.

Comment: That's because Flash ignores **any** script if you export it to any video format, or animated GIF, or PNG sequence. The result of export will always look exactly like main timeline preview (you can play it in the editor with ENTER key).